# Is it efficient to handle endianness while using an Uint8Array?

Tags: javascript

I'll need to use an instance of `Uint8Array` as the memory of a programming language.

I'll need to represent numbers in this memory (i.e., double, and others), however I'm not sure if I should order the composing bytes of these numbers in the current platform endianness, or in a permanent endianness. I'd like to know which of these ways are faster, any ideas? Or will the performance be independent from the platform's endianness, since I'll represent them manually (will `DataView` be faster for representing them at the current endianness?)?

My platform's endianness is basically little-endian.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you deal with the endianness of the numbers in your language yourself and treat everything as single bytes (`Uint8Array`), there will be quite some overhead but I don't think it will differ between the endiannesses you might choose. And of course, dealing with endianness yourself is not really an option for floating point numbers.

If you want to get more performance, you'd use the platform endianness, i.e. a `Uint16Array` or `Uint32Array` on the same memory buffer.

If you need control over the endianness regardless of the platform, you should use a `DataView` and pass the respective flag to its methods. I would expect this to be faster than dealing with the endianess yourself, especially if the intended endianness is the same as the platform's one and you align them properly on the buffer. The method call might incur a little overhead though; depends on how efficiently it is inlined.

I would recommend a `DataView` for your usecase, simply because it makes writing code much easier. If you need to optimise performance later, you can always try out the other approaches and benchmark them on (each of) your target platforms with the target JS engine versions.

Comment: Hm, for reducing the lookup of `DataView` methods I can reference them on some other where (i.e., mangled variable), right? Though I'll need to pass the this context everytime I do this with the call method, too. I'll try to apply your suggestion of using `Uint16Array`, etc... I can separate memory to put these numbers. At least these interfaces are supported in IE10.

Comment: Nah, the lookup of the methods will be properly optimised, there's nothing to do there (using `method.call(obj)` is probably worse actually). I meant the overhead of the *call* itself that might matter.

Comment: Excuse me, so, well, are getters optimized? Could you link me something about that? 0_º

Comment: If by "getters" you refer to the accessing of the method properties, yes, [they are optimised by hidden classes and inline caches](https://github.com/v8/v8/wiki/Design%20Elements). If you refer to the indexed access of the array values, yes they are heavily optimised as well.